# Shared WordPress install of 2 blogs on separate subdomains, unique content

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

What I am looking for is a way to have two different websites with different content on separate tld's to both use a subdomain i.e. "blog" from the same installation of WordPress.

For example:

blog.mydomain.com
blog.mydomain.net

So that visitors to one get the same blog design/layout, but specific content & vice-versa.

Is this possible on WordPress?

Comment: Why do they need the same installation of WordPress? You can install the same theme on both installations.

Comment: You could, but you'd have to add a simple function to check which domain is coming in, and then swap the theme based on that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a [Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) would work well for this. You can run multiple sites on a single instance of WordPress. All sites in the network can share plugins and themes, but also have their own plugins and themes. All of the sites will have completely separate content.

Since the sites are going to be on separate domains you'll also need the [MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin.